# $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition is not returning value in android device ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 100000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
  var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  alert(lng);
}, function(err) {
  // error
  alert("err");
});
```

I enabled gps also.. somebody please help me with this. I increased the timeout and checked but error function is calling.

My android device is lenovo A7000.. In emulator also is not showing..

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: `var posOptions = {timeout: 3000, maximumAge: 90000, enableHighAccuracy: false};` I changed to this one.. in some devices u have to use this code to get `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout: 2000, enableHighAccuracy: true});`

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. I will try this.

Comment: getting same problem is there any proper solution for that? getting error alert

Comment: @ojuskulkarni No proper solution got. I just used the code as mentioned in the comment, if it is throwing error then I'm calling the function which I wrote in the question. If both are unable to fetch then I gave a option to manually select the location from google maps.